# Stochastic order symbols - Intuition

Tags: econometrics, random-variable, convergence, notation

I apologize for the following set of questions, which may seem trivial.

Let $X_n$ denote a sequence of random variables. Then,

1. $X_n = o_p(1)$ means that $\lim_{{n \to \infty}} X_n = 0$.

I can use the same notation for any consistent estimator $\hat{\theta}$ for $\theta$. Thus, I express

$$
\hat{\theta} - \theta = o_p(1).
$$

Is that correct?

From the slides, I learned that

2. $X_n = O_p(1)$ implies that $X_n$ is bounded in probability. What does this mean? Can you explain it in plain English? Why do I write $X_n = O_p(1)$ when a random variable $X_n$ converges in distribution?
3. Also from the slides, I encountered the statement: consider the estimator $\hat{\beta}$ with a well-known limiting distribution (normal), then express:

$$
\hat{\beta} = \beta + O_p(n^{-1/2}).
$$

What does this mean?

4. Lastly, when I read that the estimator is biased of $O(1/T)$, what does this signify?